# Shopware 5 - Column name not changing via snippet

Tags: symfony, extjs, shopware, shopware5

I have created a Free text field in `s_articles_attributes` table and also marked it as translatable, when i am viewing `items > overview` and enabling that column, the column name isn't changed to what i put in snippet.

Does anybody know how can i make it translate according to my snippet. I thought it should be straightforward. or is there something extra i should be doing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippets for attributes need to follow a special scheme.

- First of all the snippet itself needs to be in the namespace `backend/attribute_columns`
- Then the naming of the snippet key is important:

  - for labels: `<attbribute_table>_<attribute_name>_label`
  - for support texts: `<attbribute_table>_<attribute_name>_supportText`
  - for help texts: `<attbribute_table>_<attribute_name>_helpText`

So for your case the snippet key has to look like this: `s_articles_attributes_warehouse_us_label`. Also don't forget to create it in the right namespace.

You can find more about this in our documentation: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/attribute-system/#attribute-label-translations